# Why doesn't my $scope reflect my controller being initialized?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Question:**

Why is `{{ name }}` resulting in blank?

**Plunker:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/32t8u4VL9BiuhHcC80LF?p=preview

**Script:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

app.directive('portal', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div><span>Header</span><div ng-transclude></div><span>Footer</span></div>'
  }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<portal ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{ name }}, let's see if Angular is working at all... 1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 + '!' }}</p>
</portal>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the `ng-app` and `mg-controller` on a parent `<div/>` and things will work as intended.

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <portal>
      <p>Hello {{ name }}, let's see if Angular is working at all... 1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 + '!' }}</p>
    </portal>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you tell me why I need to do that, though - that is why you can't have a ngTransclude directive with an ngApp and ngController in the same element?

Comment: Not off the top of my head but my guess is how the directive is scoped with ngTransclude.  I personally never saw `hg-app` on a custom directive as the documentation recommends to have `hg-app` on the parent of your whole angular application.

Comment: Yeah I know about Angular's recommendation.  It's just since I have multiple SPA's with naming collisions and because angular offers neither namespaces nor dynamic loading and unloading of modules and I have common content across those sites, I decided that I could use a directive to wrap each "app" with a common header and footer. I wanted to have the `ngApp` on the same element as said directive for convenience.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change the portal to a div, and you'll see that it's your directive that's not working, not your controller.

This works:

```
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <portal>
      <p>Hello {{ name }}, let's see if Angular is working at all... 1 + 2 = {{ 1 + 2 + '!' }}</p>
    </portal>
  </div>
```

Comment: I saw--by 29 seconds.  :)